# How do you plot one distribution on top of the other in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I encounter this type of graphs very often in scientific papers:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGFCM.png)

Is this two plots made separately and joined in ggplot by gridding?

Comment: Those don't look like ggplots, but if you were to use ggplot that's the easiest way to do it. See the `patchwork` package for a nice interface to put plots together and make sure the axes line up.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Irakli:

Here is some simple example of subplot using [Plotly](https://plot.ly/r/) and [subplots()](https://plot.ly/r/subplots/):

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# plot1
fig1 = plot_ly(data = mtcars, type = 'scatter', mode='markers', x = ~mpg, y= ~hp, name = "HP")

# plot2
fig2 = plot_ly(data = mtcars, type = 'scatter', mode= 'markers', x = ~mpg,y = ~drat, name="Drat")

subplot(fig1, fig2, shareX = T, nrows = 2)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the kind introduction and for the answer. I didn't think it would be this easy.

Comment: In your example image it seems to be a time series forecast. There are some libraries that do this.
Like library Prophet: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/prophet.pdf

 Or ARIMA: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.11/topics/Arima .

If you provide some data, more easily will be to reproduce that plots.

Comment: I was just curious and wanted to know how to make it. So I don't really have data to visualise for now. But I'll keep it in my general knowledge inventory. 
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Another option for obtaining a similar plot can be achieved using `cowplot` package. Here is an example using the mtcars dataset.

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)

#Create first plot
p1<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, 
                   y = disp)) +
  geom_point() 

#Create second plot
p2<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, 
                       y = hp)) +
  geom_point()+ 
  #Remove x axis ticks, title and text
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

#Create a canvas and draw the two plots with different sizes.
#x and y define the plot's lower left corner where each plot will be set (0-1)
# width and height can be interpreted as the proportion (0-1) of the original
#plot to be used to draw each plot
p3<-ggdraw()+
  draw_plot(p1,x=0,y=0,width=1,height=0.7)+
  draw_plot(p2,x=0,y=0.7,width=1,height=0.3)
p3
```

[image: cowplot]

Comment: Thank you very much. Both examples perfectly serve the purpose.